# How to capture value from a javascript function called from a Component when onClick activates

Tags: javascript, angular

So I haven't seen a way to do this, I've seen it done and explained but between components.

I have this template:

```
  template: `<input value="Date" type="text" class="datepicker" onclick ="myCalendar()" >
```

This works. I managed to get the date selected on a variable doing this:

```
onSet: function(context) {
        foo = new Date(context.select);
```

**So I now want to have that variable, that value, passed to the component that makes the call to the function**, so, once I've done that, I can make an http request with that value, and THEN pass what's retorned from the request to the next component.

Edit:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'cal',
  template: `<input value="date" type="text" class="datepicker" onclick ="myCalendar()" >
`,
  directives: []
})
export class CalendarioDentro {
  constructor() {

      }    
}
```

myCalendar function:

```
 var foo;
function myCalendar (){

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    onSet: function(context) {
        foo = new Date(context.select);
        var curr_date = foo.getDate();
        var curr_month = foo.getMonth();

        var curr_year = foo.getFullYear();
        var dateFormated=(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
        console.log(dateFormated);

    }
});
}
```

I am sorry for not making enough sense. I am new to this web world and it's taking me some time to learn to express properly. The idea is that I have a javascript function that performs an action: changes date shown by a calendar. I want to capture that date, so I can make an HTTP request to a REST service I've programmed in Java, so that I can use the information returned on the next component.

But I'm stuck in the first phase. I do have the value of the date, but I don't know how to pass it to the component that calls the javascript function. As far as I know, I need to do that so that I can make a GET Http request.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me. Can you please add more code (full component code) to make it more obvious how the stuff is related.

Comment: I just did, sorry for making no sense

Comment: I can't help you with jQuery but you should strive to avoid jQuery when you work with Angular2. Id suggest you work through the tutorials at http://angular.io

Comment: I read them non-stop. Whenever I use javascript or jquery is because I'm using something like materializecss or some similar concept that was kind of required (I don't know if people code that stuff on their own but I sure can't). Admittedly I have a few of those, so it might prove a problem, but yeah the idea behind it is not so much code as it is I'm taking something that looks good and is done and accessible.

Comment: It's common that people use jQuery components but you should strive to avoid it if you can achieve it without jQuery as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. I think a simple solution would be to add `[(ngModel)]` to your input. You then handle the `onClose()` event in your datepicker plugin.

Here is a quick example:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'cal',
    template: `<input value="date" name="date" type="text" class="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="date">`
})
export class CalendarioDentro implements OnInit {
   date: any;

   ngOnInit() {
       $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            onSet: function(context) {
                foo = new Date(context.select);
                var curr_date = foo.getDate();
                var curr_month = foo.getMonth();

                var curr_year = foo.getFullYear();
                var dateFormated=(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
                console.log(dateFormated);

            }, 
            onClose: function() {
                // Your code here
                // You can access the date like this:
                console.log(this.date)

            }
        });
   }
}
```

I've moved the plugin initialization to the OnInit [Lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html). I found that this is a good place to initialize jquery code, but i agree with Günter Zöchbauer that you should try to avoid jquery when ever possible. With all of the tools that come with Angular 2 jquery simply seams unnecessary to me.

Comment: Ok, that worked first try. I'm completely amazed. I REALLY have trouble connecting this type of things, so I'm truly thankful. I even see the log triggering when it closes, which is a big improvement over what I could have got. Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't mention it. Angular 2 can be a bit tricky at first, but you really see the benefits in the long run.